# Adding in-app shortcut to file, anywhere on file system, when targeting Android 10/11 and using Scoped Storage (or not!)

Tags: android, file, mediastore, android-external-storage, android-storage

I want to let the user select a file on his filesystem (any type ideally), be it on internal memory, **external sd cards** or on a cloud service (using the filechooser)

I know that with scoped storage apps can no longer read and write from directories that are not app-specific. I thought what I would do would be have the user select the file, read the file and then copy it over to my apps scoped storage (context.filesDir()?).

I have been trying for a few hours to get the absolute path of the created File object from the user-selected file, but it never worked. Here is some of my code:

```
val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(Intent().setType("*/*").setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT),
            getString(R.string.select_files_or_documents_you_wish_to_pin))
    try {
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_CODE_DESTINATION_PIN_FILE_CHOOSER)
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, activity?.getString(R.string.no_file_chooser_client_installed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_DESTINATION_PIN_FILE_CHOOSER)
        uriOfSelectedFile = intent?.data.path
}
```

Then later when consulting the file:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            activity?.application?.let { application ->
                intent.setDataAndType(uriOfSelectedFile, uriOfSelectedFile.mimeType(application))
                startActivity(intent)
            }
```

In order to get the absolute path to create a File() that exists, I have tried many approaches.
All of this when I was using the manifest flag requestLegacyExternalStorage = true, read/write external storage permissions, etc.

I used the following code to no avail

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {

String path = null;
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

if(cursor == null){
    path = uri.getPath()
}
else{
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]);
    path = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
}

return ((path == null || path.isEmpty()) ? (uri.getPath()) : path);
```

}

I tried lots of other solutions so I could get the full absolute path in order to copy the file, never with any success. For now I just sort of gave up and check the chosen URI for indications that the file is on external storage and I show a failure to the user saying it isnt possible.

Has anyone done this recently, using MediaStore / Scoped storage and targeting Android 10 or Android 11?

**Edit for clarifications**

- I can create a file object like this val file = File(uri.path)
- When I call file.exists() it returns false
- When I try to open an input stream with the file or the Uri directly I get a NoFileFoundException
- For MediaStore I also tried no projection, _ID and DATA
- I want to copy the file to the app's directory, ie. context.filesDir

Comment: `In order to get the absolute path ` You will not even try to convert a nice uri to a file path. Even if you could you would not have access at Android 10+.

Comment: `In order to get the absolute path to create a File() that exists,` ???? Why would one try to create a file that already exists? That makes no sence. ANd the user choosed a file so it does exist i would think. Better tell what you want.

Comment: `in order to copy the file` If you wanna copy the file the uses choosed than you can use the obtained uri directly to open an input stream. But why does your subject not mention that you wanna copy a file if that is all? Please add an `android` tag to this post.

Comment: Further you should tell where you wanna copy the file to.

Comment: `MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA` FYI: On Android 10+ the .DATA column is not in use anymore.

Comment: @blackapps I responded to your comments in the edit

Comment: Well that is not much. `When I try to open an input stream with the file or the Uri directly I get a NoFileFoundException` Try it in onActivityResult. Put the used code there so we can check . Edit 1 is nonsense as said before.

Comment: `I want to copy the file to the app's directory, ie. context.filesDir` You should put that in the first sentence of your post.